# Override Safari 11 audio/video auto play prevention

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen a number of threads on apple forums regarding this, but can't find the correct post on stack overflow regarding this, certainly with no answers.

I am working on a app, which works as a pinned browser app. We require audio instructions to continuously play. So expecting user prompts is not an option. I understand why this is a good option to stop adverts and annoying websites, but auto play is sometimes wanted/needed by the user. IE it still works for big Apps such as Netflix or Youtube.

Does anybody know a solution or work around for this problem?

Comment: To my understanding you'll need to write the app in Swift/Objective-C to get around this limitation. iOS locks down their browsers in this regard to the point that html/js just can't prevent it.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for your response, sounds like quite an a serious undertaking to make this work.